# How to change one value in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSMutableDictionary with one key and it has the following values.

[image]

How can I change the value in item2 from 1 to 0? That's the only change I need.

The only way I have found is to recreate this whole key from scratch, change that one value and then delete that key and replace it with a new one. Is there any easier solution than that?

Comment: `dictionary[keyForItem2] = @0;`

Comment: there is no key for item2. What is? "keyForItem2"

Comment: sorry, miss this thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume you get `dict` as an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` somehow:

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [dict[@"07:00 AM.infoKey"] mutableCopy];
tmp[2] = @"0";
dict[@"07:00 AM.infoKey"] = tmp;
```

Unfortunately with nested arrays in dictionaries, the arrays aren't automatically mutable so there isn't any better method to doing so, like you observed.

Comment: I keep getting compile error that mutableCopy not found

Comment: @SamBudda Sorry, forgot that the return value of the subscripts is a general `id` not `id<NSMutableCopying>`. This should work, if there's a warning cast the return.